# How to run unoconv without xServer

Tags: xserver, openoffice-writer

I want to run unoconv on Cent OS machine server obviously without any GUI. Unoconv uses OpenOffice with -headless parameter, but it does not work either.

I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/openoffice.org3/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: 
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
```

Is there a simple way to run unoconv on the server?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is fixed. I just needed to install **openoffice.org-headless** package.

Comment: But now I get error:

**unoconv: UnoException during conversion in <class '__main__.com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException'>: 
ERROR: The provided document cannot be converted to the desired format. (code: 2074)**

What's the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link http://www.openvpms.org/documentation/install-openoffice-headless-service-ubuntu describes that you have to install  openoffice.org-writer openoffice.org-draw or  you will get an error message: This url is not supported.

I install this two packages and run unoconv without X sever and it work fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you couldn't run the soffice command was because libreoffice-headless.x86_64 package was not installed. The conversion command works properly after installing it.
[how to install](https://www.openvpms.org/documentation/install-openoffice-headless-service-ubuntu)